# css position issue displaying epub file

Tags: html, css, epub

please I need help in positioning my displayed epub. Its supposed to display in a div called area, but I find it very difficult to add margins or paddings to the div area, it just doesn't take effect.

At least to make the epub a bit far from the margins of the page.

Below is my html:

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#reader {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 10;
  left: 20;
  bottom: 10;
  right: 20;
  background: wheat;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#reader #toolbar {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  padding: 10px;
}

#reader #toolbar .left {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#reader #toolbar .center {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#reader #toolbar .right {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#reader #area {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

#reader #area div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="reader">
  <input type="file" id="bookChooser">
  <select id="toc"></select>
  <div id="area">
    <!-- Display epub here with margin or padding to format the epub or justify epub -->
  </div>
  <button id="prev" type="button"><</button>
  <button id="next" type="button">></button>
</div>
```

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to all who viewed the question, finally I was able to figure out where my mistake was, it was in the css, I was applying the margin and padding to the divs inside of area, instead of applying to area directly, I will post the solution below. Thanks.

```css
#reader #area {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#reader #area div {
  position: absolute;
  /*All the below, was not necessary because it is already taken care of above*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Thanks all